# Error #2032 : preview the swf file from xml data (Xcelsius)

Tags: flash, xcelsius

Whenever I try to preview the swf file from xml data in xcelsius(dashboard),
error occurs

> #2032 cannot access external / connection type : xml data

I also try to change the global security settings of adobe flash player and change the version  of flash to 22 from 26 but nothing changed.

But, one of my colleague's computer does not show the above message, but others' are same with me. So, I think the settings of server is not the cause of this symptoms.  (Also, I have crossdomain.xml on tomcat/webapps/root)

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: It indeed seems like a security restriction error. Also "*try to change the global security settings*" is not equal to "*set the security settings right*".

Comment: Are you adding the dashboards into SAP B1 or something? Or are you using them on the web?